# MySQL relationship schema

Tags: mysql

Assuming MySQL with a `users` table like

```
id | user_name | total_likes | updated_at
```

and a `likes` table like

```
id | user_id | like
```

What I need is to when the `likes` table gets updated/inserted/deleted then the `users.updated_at` associated with `likes.user_id` gets updated to the current date. Further when an insert happens to the `likes` table, then `users.total_likes` increases by 1 value.

I can do all the above with queries however, I am trying to use the power of relationships in MySQL. Please can you advise?

Comment: Why does the data need to be duplicated in the first place?  Why not just add a date/time column to `likes` to store when a record was added and query that table any time you need to get the "total" and "updated at"?

Comment: Thanks @David. This example is simplified for the demonstration only.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you're asking then?  What are you trying to do and in what way is it not working as expected?

Comment: Thanks. The actual scenario is way more complex. For example, several tables need to get updated and incremented. However, if this is doable in MySQL without writing queries, I can extend to cover all of my scenarios

Comment: I guess the database concept you're looking for is just "triggers" then?  The schema shown in the question can certainly be improved to eliminate the duplication of data.  But if your intent is to keep the current schema and you're just looking to update records in response to the creation/updating of other records, triggers do just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David mentioned above, you are most likely looking for triggers. Something like this:

```
Delimiter //  
CREATE TRIGGER ai_likes AFTER INSERT ON likes  
FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN  
INSERT INTO users (updated_at) VALUES  
NOW()  
WHERE id = NEW.id;  
UPDATE users SET total_likes = (total_likes + 1)   
WHERE id = NEW.id;  
END//  
Delimiter ;


CREATE TRIGGER au_likes AFTER UPDATE ON likes  
FOR EACH ROW  
INSERT INTO users (updated_at) VALUES  
NOW()   
WHERE id = NEW.id;

CREATE TRIGGER ad_likes AFTER DELETE ON likes  
FOR EACH ROW  
INSERT INTO users (updated_at) VALUES  
NOW()   
WHERE id = NEW.id;
```